# How many solutions

Tags: permutations, combinations

If I want to have company A owns company B and there are 195 countires in the world and company A and Comapny B don't have to be in the same country mow many different permutations/solutions are there and what is the formula please?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. 

Also have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/75923

Comment: Is the fact that company A owns company B important? Also by "don't have to be in the same country", do you mean "cannot be in the same country" or "they can possibly in the same country"?

Answer (score 1):

If every country needs to have a branch compulsorily, then it good enough to consider which countries are chosen for A, the rest will automatically be B.

So, you can have 1, 2, 3, $\dots$ , 195 branches for A.

So total combinations possible is : $$\sum_{k = 0}^{195} {195 \choose k} = 2^{195}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at it is :

Choose a country now two things can happen : either it has a branch of A or a branch of B. So 2 choices are possible. Now if you go on assigning branches to all 195 countries, the number of possible options in the end turns out to be $2 \times 2 \times \dots \times 2$ (195 times).

So we have answer : $2^{195}$.

Comment: Maybe don't write the "!" as it might lead to confusion.